# How to replace part of a string with an added condition

Tags: string, replace

#### The problem:

The objective is to convert: `"tan(x)*arctan(x)"`

Into: `"np.tan(x)*np.arctan(x)"`

#### What I've tried:

```py
s = "tan(x)*arctan(x)"
s = s.replace('tan','np.tan')
```

```
Out: np.tan(x)*arcnp.tan(x)
```

However, using pythons `replace` method resulted in `arcnp.tan`.

Taking one additional step:

```py
s = s.replace('arcnp.', 'np.arc')
```

```
Out: np.tan(x)*np.arctan(x)
```

Achieves the desired result... but this solution is sloppy and inefficient.

**Is there a more efficient solution to this problem?**

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job:

```js
var string = 'tan(x)*arctan(x)';
var res = string.replace(/\b(?:arc)?tan\b/g,'np.$&');
console.log(res);
```

**Explanation:**

```
/               : regex delimiter
    \b          : word boundary, make sure we don't have any word character before
    (?:arc)?    : non capture group, literally 'arc', optional
    tan         : literally 'tan'
    \b          : word boundary, make sure we don't have any word character after
/g              : regex delimiter, global flag
```

**Replace:**

```
$&  : means the whole match, ie. tan or arctan
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to solve your issue. Following code is in javascript. Since, u didn't mention the language you are using.

```js
var string = 'tan(x)*arctan(x)*xxxtan(x)';

console.log(string.replace(/([a-z]+)?(tan)/g,'np.$1$2'));
```